# registration failed [AxiosError: Network Error], how should i even resolve this?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, axios

I was building a login page for my project when i ran into this error! Help would be much appreciated thanks in advance

I tried adding data to MongoDB but instead kept on receiving this error

this is my backend code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.03lvgad.mongodb.net/",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Success");
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is running");
});

const User = require("./models/user");
const Message = require("./models/message");

//endpoint for Signup

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, image } = req.body;

  //new user
  const newUser = new User({ name, email, password, image });

  //save user to database
  newUser
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "User registered succesfully" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error in register", err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Error! User not registered" });
    });
});
```

and this is my frontend code:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Pressable,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import axios from "axios";

const RegisterScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const handleRegister = () => {
    const user = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      image: image,
    };

    // send a POST  request to the backend API to register the user
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/register", user)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        Alert.alert(
          "Registration successful",
          "You have been registered Successfully"
        );
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setPassword("");
        setImage("");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(
          "Registration Error",
          "An error occurred while registering"
        );
        console.log("registration failed", error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <KeyboardAvoidingView>
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 100,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#4A55A2", fontSize: 17, fontWeight: "600" }}>
            Register
          </Text>

          <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, fontWeight: "600", marginTop: 15 }}>
            Register To your Account
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
          <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "600", color: "gray" }}>
              Name
            </Text>

            <TextInput
              value={name}
              onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
              style={{
                fontSize: email ? 18 : 18,
                borderBottomColor: "gray",
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                marginVertical: 10,
                width: 300,
              }}
              placeholderTextColor={"black"}
              placeholder="Enter your name"
            />
          </View>

          <View>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "600", color: "gray" }}>
              Email
            </Text>

            <TextInput
              value={email}
              onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
              style={{
                fontSize: email ? 18 : 18,
                borderBottomColor: "gray",
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                marginVertical: 10,
                width: 300,
              }}
              placeholderTextColor={"black"}
              placeholder="enter Your Email"
            />
          </View>

          <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "600", color: "gray" }}>
              Password
            </Text>

            <TextInput
              value={password}
              onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              style={{
                fontSize: email ? 18 : 18,
                borderBottomColor: "gray",
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                marginVertical: 10,
                width: 300,
              }}
              placeholderTextColor={"black"}
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          </View>

          <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "600", color: "gray" }}>
              Image
            </Text>

            <TextInput
              value={image}
              onChangeText={(text) => setImage(text)}
              style={{
                fontSize: email ? 18 : 18,
                borderBottomColor: "gray",
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                marginVertical: 10,
                width: 300,
              }}
              placeholderTextColor={"black"}
              placeholder="Image"
            />
          </View>

          <Pressable
            onPress={handleRegister}
            style={{
              width: 200,
              backgroundColor: "#4A55A2",
              padding: 15,
              marginTop: 50,
              marginLeft: "auto",
              marginRight: "auto",
              borderRadius: 6,
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                color: "white",
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: "bold",
                textAlign: "center",
              }}
            >
              Register
            </Text>
          </Pressable>

          <Pressable
            onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
            style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "gray", fontSize: 16 }}>
              Already Have an account? Sign in
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default RegisterScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

in the front end code if i change the axios.post method to localhost:8081 which is the default for metro bundler the code runs without any issue but the data is not being added to MongoDB, i get that 8081 is for metro and it has nothing to do with my backend API which is running on 8000, but setting the localhost to 8000 just downright pops up the AxiosError

Comment: Can you try changing the url from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: no use still the same error :(

Comment: Guys got the solution changing the localhost to 10.0.2.2 worked

Comment: Yes the issue is with sending `localhost` as a url, always refer back to your local host ip address instead when testing to avoid having these errors.